# Set log message in non-interactive org-todo?

Tags: org-mode

In Emacs 23.3.1, I have an org file with (inter alia) the state `CANCELED(c@)`.  I want to iterate over a subtree (which works fine with `org-map-entries`), and then according to user input set the state to `CANCELED` with a logged note `Reason`.

If I call `(org-todo "CANCELED")`, the state of the item is set properly, but I'm left with an `*Org Note*` buffer that is ignored because my loop carries on.

How can I set the log note non-interactively?  If it is not possible, are there better alternatives to `(progn (switch-to-buffer "*Org Note*") (insert "Reason") (org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c))` (which also doesn't work :-))?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `advice`'ing `org-todo` would be too much work as the note logger is very integrated into the overall framework and opted, inspired by [Worg](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-hacks.html#sec-1-6-2), for a more traditional keyboard macro approach:

`(kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ("\C-c\C-tcReason\C-c\C-c" 0 "%d")) nil)`